# Unit Test mocking AWS Lambda Function with global section, Python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, function, aws-lambda, mocking

I'm writing a python lambda with an initialisation to an external service in the global section of the lambda. How do I mock this external dependency as it is initialised at the creation of my class?

data_load.py

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch,

# Global section - executed once for the life time of the container
def get_elastic_search_connection():
    try:
        client = Elasticsearch(
            hosts=[{'host': "host", 'port': 9191}],
            use_ssl="true",
            verify_certs="true",
            connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection)
        return client
    except Exception as e:
        LOGGER.error("Unable to connect to ES")
        exit(1)

es_client = get_elastic_search_connection()


# handler section - executed once per function invocation
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    es_client.bulk(body="body", index="index", doc_type="doc", _source=False)
```

In my test, as soon as the import statement imports data_load.py, it tries to initialise the global section of the lambda, which tries to make a http connection to host address.  How do I create a partial mock of data_loay.py so that I can test the lambda_handler method?  The es_client has to be initialised in the global section.  How do I dependency inject a mock into the global section?

test_data_load.py

```py
import unittest
import search_lambda.data_load.data_load


class TestDatLoad(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_data_load(self):
        print("Hello")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```